# Unconstrained Minimisation with fminunc, with Constraints in the Objective Function, vs Use of Constrained Minimisation Functions, e.g. fmincon, sqp?

Tags: octave, nonlinear-optimization

I have a partially constrained (in the parameters) minimisation problem which I am currently solving using Octave's fminunc function, but with constraints being applied within the objective function itself by use of if statements to produce a realmax cost if any constraint is violated.

However, the problem could also be solved by using fmincon with upper and lower bounds of the parameters being explicitly provided as constraints. I could also, probably, use other more 'complicated' functions such as sqp to solve the problem too.

The problem I'm solving is:- *find values 'a' through 'f'* such that

```
C1 - a = C2 * K
C3 + b = C4 * K
C5 - c = C6 * K
C7 - d = C8 * K
C9 + e = C10 * K
C11 - f = C12 * K

where all the C1, C2... are known, different valued constants 0 < C < 1
where K = 1 - a + b - c - d + e - f
and K > 0
and where  a, c, d and f are individually subject to constraints on their values
```

and where, theoretically, the minimum cost of the objective function should be 0.

What is the best approach to take? Is hacking the use of fminunc somehow going to lead to unpredictable/pathological solutions? Is it better to use "the right tool for the job" and use a function specifically meant for constrained minimisation?

This might sound like it is a philosophical question but my concern is actually to do with accuracy of solutions and, to a lesser degree, ease of programming and computational efficiency.

Comment: I'm unable to give proper references, so I'm going to put this as a comment rather than as an answer ... but yes, an unconstrained algorithm is not designed to acommodate constraints, and therefore is not the right choice for such a problem. The 'constraint' variants rely on specific algorithms which deal with constraints appropriately. By artificially injecting them in your function instead, you may be causing suboptimal sampling and numerical artefacts. As you said. Stick to the right tool for the job. As for sqp vs fmincon, I'd say the main plus for fmincon is that it also exists in matlab.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/fminunc.html) available with `help fminunc` does provide a little bit of  answer.

> The algorithm used by fminunc is a gradient search which depends on the objective function being differentiable. If the function has discontinuities it may be better to use a derivative-free algorithm such as fminsearch.

Returning `realmax` will mess up the gradient calculation. Worst case scenario is it will flood with `NaN`s and `Inf`s.

You can set "Display" [option](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/optimset.html) of the optimizer to "iter" and find out if your program converges solely because it never touches boundaries or if the `fminunc` does have some failsafes.

Also, note the `fminsearch`, it is a simplex method for optimizing any arbitrary function.